# c++ txt to vector failure

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Can't read/get text file(.txt)  to vector, tried 3 approaches found on web (numbered 0-1-2). So far got number of words (distance algorithm), file size (didn't include code), but no vector. Please point me to mistake. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;

void intoVector (ifstream  &stream, vector<string> &vector) {
    string s;
    getline (stream, s);
    istringstream iss (s);
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(vector));

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string s1="text.txt";
    ifstream file (s1);

    if (!file) {
        cout<<"Couldn't find file"<<endl; exit(1);
    }else {cout<<"File is found"<<endl;}


    //words count - o.k.
    istream_iterator<string> start(file), end;
    cout<<"Word count: "<<distance(start, end)<<endl;//iterator distance - difference beteween 2 iterators, type ptrdiff_t


    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout<<"File isn't open"<<endl;
    }


    //0)try
    vector<string> vec1;
    intoVector(file, vec1);
    cout<<vec1.size()<<endl;                            //result- 0


    //1) try1
    vector<string> text1(start, end);
    cout<<"Vector size "<<text1.size()<<endl;        //result - 1, 1st word
    copy(text1.begin(), text1.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));    


    //2)try2
    vector<string> vec2;
    string s2;
    while (getline(file, s2)) {
        vec2.push_back(s2);
    }
    cout<<"vec size   "<<vec2.size()<<endl;       //Result -0
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My bad. Need either get text line by line (strings to vector) or find a way to iterate through text word by word (to get to word of certain number[index]).

Comment: All approached are working when I disable ifstream_iterator  (distance algorithm). Previously had to make file size calculation as a function (outside main) 'cause it was conflicting with mentioned iterator.

Answer (score 0):

All approached are working when I disable ifstream_iterator (distance algorithm). Previously had to make file size calculation as a function (outside main) 'cause it was conflicting with mentioned iterator